# How to convert date using offset by moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am trying to convert a date by using offset or timezone. I am receiving the following possible attribute for converting a date:

```
Date is: 2019-04-09T14:01:00.000+0000"

"timezone": {
  "longName": "(GMT+05:45) Kathmandu",
  "shortName": "GMT+5.75",
  "offset": 5.75,
  "dst": false
}
```

How to convert above date according to above timezone JSON attributes.